# mod_rewrite Replace string in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to achievement replacement of a string in a URL on the Apache level.

So I have a URL like :

https://barred.v.com/sorter.do?clientId=testvalue1

I want this to be redirected to

https://barred.v.com/sorter.do?nai=testvalue1

So look for clientId and replace by nai .

Is this even possible at the Apache layer ? with mod_rewrite ?

Answer (score 1):

In the root folder of

```
http://example.com/
```

upload an `.htaccess` file, containing the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} clientId=(.+)
RewriteRule ^sorter\.do http://%{HTTP_HOST}/sorter.do?nai=%1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: It seems to work only when I do
    Rewrite Rule ^\/sorter.do http://%{HTTP_HOST}/sorter.do?nai=%1 [NC,L]

But I am also trying to do : RewriteRule ^\/sorter.do\?clientId(.*)$ /sorter.do?$nai$1 [R=301,L,NE] but it doesnt work. Any idea whats wrong with it ?

Comment: In your second example above, it looks like you're trying to rewrite the query string using the RewriteRule. But you can't do that. You need to capture a variable from the RewriteCond as in the example in the post above. Can you give a concrete example of where the lines in the post above don't work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /sorter\.do\?clientId=([^\s]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule ^sorter\.do$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/?nai=%1 [NC,L]
```